# How to change connectionsPerHost and threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier configuration in mongdb through mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, configuration, mongo-shell, distributed-database, database

I need to change `threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier` and `connectionsPerHost` values in mongodb from their default value through mongo shell instead of a program. How can I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are settings for the Java driver. You can't set them through the mongo shell because they are properties of the Java client and not the mongo shell or the server itself.

Comment: I also realised it. The solution which I finally found was related to modification in java driver. Thanks for your information.